# Same JS file loaded twice after it's minified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I purchased a web template from a market. Then I have minification applied in several js files to reduce bandwidth and improve performance. However, now those JS files are called twice leading to a consequence opposite to my original purpose.

The second time those files are called by multiple other JS files through XHR.  The url was similar to `file.js?_=1454776019244` rather than `file.js`. So my guess is that the minified JS files are not recognized correctly by other files as minifier would usually change the variable name to reduce characters. Of course, it's just a guess. What could cause the problem?

By the way, I did not apply yepnope.js to manage the JS file.

Comment: Something is appending timestamp to request, effectively disabling cache. Not sure what other answer do you want

Comment: that is jQuery appending timestamp when script is inside ajax content. Don't include it in the ajax content if it has already been loaded

Comment: Actually an outdated version of bootstrap caused this problem. It's resolved after an up-to-date bootstrap is applied.